# How to use v-bind=$attrs in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am migrating vue 2 application to vue 3. In official docs, it is mentioned that $listeners object has been removed in Vue 3. Event listeners are now part of $attrs. It is taking non-prop attributes (class, style) as well. In my vue 2 application, there is one icon-button custom component and it is looking like this below.

**Icon-component:**

```
<template>
    <vu-button v-bind="buttonProps"
               :class="buttonClass"
                v-on="$listeners"         
               @click="buttonToggle">
        <vu-icon v-bind="iconProps"><slot/></vu-icon>
    </vu-button>
</template>
```

It is used in various other components.

**Parent component 1:**

```
<vu-icon-button id="sw1" medium style="left:200px;">home</vu-icon-button>
```

**Parent component 2:**

```
<vu-icon-button class="menu-detail-btn" icon="collapse_menu" icon-type="su" @click="openModal()" size="small"></vu-icon-button>
```

As of migration strategy, i removed the $listeners but not sure about those non-prop attributes and v-bind tag. How to modify those so it can be used in parent component with attributes?

Answer (score 7):

### Accessing Fallthrough Attributes in Vue 3

> You can access a component's fallthrough attributes in `<script setup>` using the `useAttrs()` API:

```js
<script setup>
import { useAttrs } from 'vue'

const attrs = useAttrs()
</script>
```

If not using `<script setup>`, attrs will be exposed as a property of the `setup()` context:

```js
export default {
  setup(props, ctx) {
    // fallthrough attributes are exposed as ctx.attrs
    console.log(ctx.attrs)
  }
}
```

### Disabling Attributes Inheritance

If you do not want a component to automatically inherit attributes, you can set `inheritAttrs: false` in the component's options.

If using `<script setup>`, you will need to declare this option using a separate, normal `<script>` block:

```js
<script>
// use normal <script> to declare options
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false
}
</script>

<script setup>
// ...setup logic
</script>
```

You can now use the `$attrs` object directly in the template. This is useful when you want to bind the attribute to a non-root element of your choice, as opposed to the automatic behaviour of attributes being inherited by the root element.

*Example:*

```html
<header>...</header>
<main v-bind="$attrs">...</main>
<footer>...</footer>
```